# NativeScript-Vue button with linear gradient background and image

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

In NativeScript with vue.js, I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to have a button which has a linear gradient background *and* shows an image above the button text.  When I set up the CSS to do that, it doesn't seem to work.

I set up a playground to demonstrate: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=kICEBa&v=1.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this simply not supported by NativeScript-Vue?

If it's not supported by CSS, is there some other way to achieve this result?

Comment: Have you tried that outside of a nativescript application?

Comment: Jonas, I only tried this inside NativeScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think having both on same element is yet supported. You may raise a feature request to support both.

Meanwhile wrap your button with a layout / content view and apply the gradient on it.

Comment: Wrapping the button in a content view works.  I updated the playground with the solution: [link](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=kICEBa&v=2)